# Hitting PHP memory limits while iterating over Drupal 8 EntityQuery results. How do I keep it down?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, drupal-8

I have a D8 API endpoint that queries for a specific content type, applies any optional conditions, transforms the result to JSON, and returns to the client. I updated the PHP memory limit to 512M and I am still running into it. There are only 1500 records in Drupal so there really shouldnt be any reason why its so bad (341KB per record?!). If I just keep pumping up the memory to get it to run, the rendered JSON is less than 2 MB.

I know PHP garbage collection is automatic so I guess there are references that are being kept around.

I made several attempts to keep it down, like batching the queries, refactoring into functions, and explicitly calling `gc_collect_cycles` but nothing makes a difference.

How do I keep the memory consumption down while iterating over the results of a Drupal EntityQuery?

```
  protected function get() {
    echo "memory (start): " . memory_get_usage() . "\n<br>";

    //some setup and validation

    $query = $this->build_query($params);
    echo "memory (build_query): " . memory_get_usage() . "\n<br>";

    $results = $query->execute();
    echo "memory (execute): " . memory_get_usage() . "\n<br>";

    $items = [];

    $chunk_size = 50;
    $chunks = array_chunk(array_values($results), $chunk_size);
    echo "memory (chunk): " . memory_get_usage() . "\n<br>";

    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
      $items = array_merge($items, $this->load_nodes($chunk));
      echo "memory (chunk loaded): " . memory_get_usage() . "\n<br>";
    }
    echo "memory (all loaded): " . memory_get_usage() . "\n<br>";

    $response = [ 'results' => $items ];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }
```

```
  protected function load_nodes($ids) {
    $items = [];
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($ids);
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $items[] = $this->transform($node); 
    }
    return $items;
  }
```

```
  protected function transform($array) {
    $new = [
      "field1" => $array['field1'],
      "field2" => $array['field2'],
      //... for about 30 more fields, with some processing/manipulation ...
    ];
    return $new;
  }
```

And the output in regards to the memory echo is:

> memory (start): 28297032 
>   memory (build_query): 29984168 
>   memory (execute): 31004048 
>   memory (chunk): 31083864 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 42175976 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 50447792 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 57609344 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 66762688 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 74555712 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 86663016 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 98514192 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 110908336 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 122792592 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 134651328 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 145622512 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 156546072 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 167805352 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 178617040 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 190400936 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 201246256 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 212387384 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 223756088 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 234898632 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 246125624 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 257136304 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 268205304 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 278744896 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 289693184 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 300491840 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 310564624 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 321204064 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 333842760 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 343723672 
>   memory (chunk loaded): 344960728 
>   memory (all loaded): 344960728

Shouldn't the memory consumption be remaining steady each iteration of `load_nodes` as GC cleans up the old references?

You'll notice that my endpoint only finishes up with 344 MB. The actually error is thrown somewhere in the Drupal core. Since I want to keep the max PHP memory at 128M, I still need to get my part of the memory down.

Comment: I managed to fix this with this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202860/unable-to-loop-through-all-nodes-in-a-content-type-and-load-them-without-hitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I don't think your assumption about garbage collection is correct in this particular case.

From Drupal 8 documentation:

> *function node_load_multiple*
>
> Loads node entities from the database.
>
> This function should be used whenever you need to load more than one
>   node from the database. **Nodes are loaded into memory and will not
>   require database access if loaded again during the same page request.**
>    [[source]](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/8.0.x)

Seems they are intended to persist throughout the duration of the page request, which would make memory consumption cumulative even with iterations.

I am actually seeing a lot of posts on Drupal forums of other developers also experiencing out of memory issues when using this function. Memory consumption will be particularly high if you are loading many nodes.

---

In order to keep memory consumption a bit lower, I recommend disable caching for your node loads by setting the cache reset parameter to true. Example:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($ids, NULL, TRUE);
```

Hope that helps :)

---

**EDIT:**

Hrmm it seems we were on the right track trying ot reset the cache, but we'll have to try another approach to resetting it. This approach is pulled from the deprecated `node_load()` function.

The class path in Drupal for the alternate reset cache method is this:

```
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache(array('NID'));
```

The fixed script would be something like:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
     ->condition($params);

$results = $query->execute();

$nids = array_keys($results);

foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);

    // Do stuff with loaded node, ex:
    // print $node->title->value;

    // Now reset the cache with the legacy reset cache
    \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache(array($nid));
}
```

Comment: Aw too bad, what happened with the test, just still hitting the memory limit?

Comment: Yep. Still hit the memory limit.

Comment: The answer that worked for me was on this thread. Add it to your answer and Ill award you the bounty. I cant let all those good Internet points go to waste. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202860/unable-to-loop-through-all-nodes-in-a-content-type-and-load-them-without-hitting

Comment: Very kind of you @Jeff and glad to hear you were able to get it working after all! I updated my answer with information from your link.

Comment: I had about 60k nodes to modify, don't know how I would have done without this help :) many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a misconception about garbage collector in PHP.

Well, the only way that the garbage collector do free a memory space is when this space is no longer referenced by any variable, meanwhile, you're always returning values from your function so that they'll be referenced by other variables in a high level functions.

you can also check about how to disable some caches in drupal, it's may help you a little depending on the cache stategy used by drupal

Comment: The items being returned are simple arrays - not the items returned by the Drupal query. They certainly shouldnt be taking up roughly 340KB per record. I'm not saving a reference to the Drupal objects returned by the query.

Comment: `the only way that the garbage collector do free a memory space is when this space is no longer referenced by any variable` - there are many exceptions to rule, there's lots of functions that free memory even when references remain, including fclose(), curl_close(), curl_multi_close(), socket_close(), and  imagedestroy(), and those are just off the top of my head, i'm probably forgetting something

Comment: those functions that you mentioned do not free memory space but free ressources, well you can tell me that those ressources consume memory and therefore when we close them memory is freed, and i can respond that if you look what i've said in my answer : garbage collector in -->PHP<-- meanwhile resources memory are freed not by garbage collector but with a hard coded mechanisme of there respective php extensions (or in some case as fclose by the core php engine itself)

Comment: you try this code <?php $handle = fopen('c://msdia80.dll', 'r');
        var_dump($handle);
        fclose($handle);
        var_dump($handle);
        return (new Response());?> at the end $handle does not equal false but still reference a resource